# Error while parsing lxml

Tags: python-3.x

While parsing XML using lxml, I get an error **"reading file objects must return bytes objects"**.  Here's the code

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
def parseXML(xmlFile):
    """
    parse the xml
    """
    data=open(xmlFile)
    xml=data.read()
    data.close()

    tree=etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
    context=etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
    for action, elem in context:
        if not elem.text:
            if not elem.text:
                text="None"
            else:
                text=elem.text
            print(elem.tag + "=>" + text)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseXML("C:\\Users\\karthik\Desktop\\xml_path\\bgm.xml")
```

BGM xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<zAppointments reminder="15">
    <appointment>
        <begin>1181251680</begin>
        <uid>040000008200E000</uid>
        <alarmTime>1181572063</alarmTime>
        <state></state>
        <location></location>
        <duration>1800</duration>
        <subject>Bring pizza home</subject>
    </appointment>
    <appointment>
        <begin>1234360800</begin>
        <duration>1800</duration>
        <subject>Check MS Office website for updates</subject>
        <location></location>
        <uid>604f4792-eb89-478b-a14f-dd34d3cc6c21-1234360800</uid>
        <state>dismissed</state>
  </appointment>
</zAppointments>
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/karthik/source/ChartAttributes/crecords", line 34, in <module>
    parseXML("C:\\Users\\karthik\\Desktop\\xml_path\\bgm.xml")
  File "C:/Users/karthik/source/ChartAttributes/crecords", line 26, in parseXML
    for action, elem in context:
  File "src\lxml\iterparse.pxi", line 208, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:150010)
  File "src\lxml\iterparse.pxi", line 193, in lxml.etree.iterparse.__next__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:149708)
  File "src\lxml\iterparse.pxi", line 221, in lxml.etree.iterparse._read_more_events (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:150208)
TypeError: reading file objects must return bytes objects
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Any reason you don't just do `xml = etree.parse(xmlFile)` directly instead of reading the file into a string and then wrapping it in StringIO?

Comment: I just followed this blog https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/11/20/python-parsing-xml-with-lxml/

Comment: Okay... well try using `etree.parse` directly with the filename and see what happens

Comment: OSError: Error reading file '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<zAppointments reminder="15">

Comment: That looks like you're passing `etree.parse` the data you've read from the file - pass it the **filename**

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the XML as a byte array rather than a character string.

Open the file in binary mode to get a `bytes` object:

```
    data=open(xmlFile, 'rb')
```

But it's probably just easier to pass the filename to LXML and let it take care of opening and reading the file:

```
from lxml import etree

def parseXML(xmlFile):
    for action, elem in etree.iterparse(xmlFile):
        text = elem.text or "None"
        print(elem.tag + "=>" + text)
```

Comment: I have added 'b' getting errorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/karthik/source/ChartAttributes/crecords", line 34, in <module>
    parseXML("C:\\Users\\karthik\Desktop\\xml_path\\bgm.xml")
  File "C:/Users/karthik/source/ChartAttributes/crecords", line 20, in parseXML
    data=open(xmlFile, 'b')
ValueError: Must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode and at most one plus

Comment: after editing rb also getting TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: it did work by opening the file in binary mode `'rb'`